# Error: Template parse errors: 'app-header' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

I created a custom component, but Karma is producing the following error. Where could I have made a mistake?

```
failed: template parsing errors:
'app-header' is not a known element:

1. If the 'appheader' is a corner component, make sure it is part of this module.

2. If the application header is a web component, and then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' with '@NgModule.schemes ' of this component to suppress this message. ("[Error ->]<app-title></app-header>"): NG:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HeaderModule } from './header/header.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    HeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**header.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

**header.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

in your app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    HeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

header.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

Comment: I found the reason of this error. There is a code in file app.component.spec.ts:
`it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });`
If you delete this code, errors will disappear. How critical is it to delete this code?